# Modifications of the window control buttons (hide, close and maximize) with Avalonia in C#

Tags: c#, avaloniaui, avalonia

I want to change the design of the buttons of the windows window and the rectangle that contains them: I would like the rectangle to be filled by my background, and to be able to change the design of the buttons

I want to remove the possibility for the user to change the size of the window, and to make it bigger, and I want to remove the Maximize button from the controls

I want to change the design of the hide button and the close button

And for the rectangle that contains the controls I would like it to be filled with my background, then I will add some pixels of thickness to the window in black to add contrast to the window

I tried different things proposed by the lib unfortunately nothing worked

Here is my code

**MainWindow.axaml :**

```
<Window xmlns="https://github.com/avaloniaui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="800" d:DesignHeight="450"
    x:Class="AvaloniaAppTest.MainWindow"
    Height="600"
    Width="900"
    Icon="/assets/icon.ico"
    Title="AppTest">
    
    <Window.Background>
            <ImageBrush Source="/assets/background.png"/>
    </Window.Background>
    
    <Grid>
            <Grid.Background>
                    <ImageBrush Stretch="UniformToFill" Source="/assets/background.png"/>
            </Grid.Background>              
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            
            <!-- Left Side -->
            <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                    <TextBlock Text="Left Click" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="20" Foreground="White"/>
                    <Button x:Name="leftStart" Content="Start" Margin="5"  Background="Yellow"/>
                    <Button x:Name="leftStop" Content="Stop" Margin="5"  Background="Yellow"/>
                    <Button x:Name="leftHotkey" Content="Hotkey" Margin="5"  Background="Yellow"/>
            </StackPanel>
            
            <!-- Right Side -->
            <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                    <TextBlock Text="Right Click" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="20" Foreground="White"/>
                    <Button Content="Start" Margin="5"  Background="Yellow"/>
                    <Button Content="Stop" Margin="5"  Background="Yellow"/>
                    <Button Content="Hotkey" Margin="5"  Background="Yellow"/>
            </StackPanel>
            
    </Grid>
```

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Comment: You seem to have posted more code than what would be reasonable for your issue. Please read [ask] and how to make a [mre]; providing a MRE helps users answer your question and future users relate to your issue.

Comment: Thanks for your advices, it should be better, I thought I was doing well by detailing precisely, and show where I was the image was mainly used to show precisely the place sometimes we can misunderstand

Answer (score 1):

By adding `WindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner" ExtendClientAreaChromeHints="NoChrome" ExtendClientAreaToDecorationsHint="True"` in the window it will hide the taskbar completely.
[image]